# Why does the return value object have two extra fields in getResources function of URLClassPath?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm reading the source code of spring boot. I found a problem when reading the `SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames`. The `URLClassPath.getResources` return the implementation of `Enumeration<Resource>`, but the value has extra two fields `name` and `check`. So, when do the two fields be added into the return value?

```
public Enumeration<Resource> getResources(final String var1, final boolean var2) {
        return new Enumeration<Resource>() {
            private int index = 0;
            private int[] cache = URLClassPath.this.getLookupCache(var1);
            private Resource res = null;

            private boolean next() {
                if (this.res != null) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    do {
                        URLClassPath.Loader var1x;
                        if ((var1x = URLClassPath.this.getNextLoader(this.cache, this.index++)) == null) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        this.res = var1x.getResource(var1, var2);
                    } while(this.res == null);

                    return true;
                }
            }

            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return this.next();
            }

            public Resource nextElement() {
                if (!this.next()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                } else {
                    Resource var1x = this.res;
                    this.res = null;
                    return var1x;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I'm using the Intellij to debug the program, the result is

[image: Debug Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result instance is an anonymous class in this case and it captures the values of the `getResources` parameters `(final String var1, final boolean var2)`.

Comment: why does the name of two vars become `name` and `check`?

Comment: Thank you, I thought I found the answer, because the name of two vars is `name` and `check` in  the source code, but I read the decompiled class file using intellij.